# LaTeX Error: Environment Checklist undefined

Tags: environments, undefined

I am trying to make a checklist using the typed-checklist package. When I compile the .tex file, latex gives me the error: "Environment Checklist undefined". I get this error when compiling the file using MacTeX and using the TexLive 2017 installation on a Linux computer (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with TeXLive installed from the Internet and not the distribution's version).

There are quite a few questions here about undefined environments, and I have read through a number of them. I have also written to the package maintainer using the email address in the documentation, but the email bounced (550). I have also compiled the package anew on the Linux box, installed the files in their appropriate locations and run mktexlsr. Still no joy.

Here is the example from the documentation that I am trying to compile:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{typed-checklist}
\begin{document}
\begin{Checklist}{Goal}
        \Goal{open}{I have a trendy haircut}
                \begin{Checklist}{Task}
                        \Task{done}{Find a hairdresser}
                        \Task{started}Make an appointment}
                        \Task{open}{Go to the hairdresser}
                \end{Checklist}
        \Goal{achieved}{I have a typed checklist}
\end{Checklist}
\end{document}
```

Here is the contents of the log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.1.5)  8 JAN 2018 15:51
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**Test_Checklist.tex
(./Test_Checklist.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.16> and hyphenation patterns for 60 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo
File: size11.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/typed-checklist/typed-checklist.s
ty
Package: typed-checklist 2016/03/30 v1.4 A package for layouting checklists
 (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks14
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks15

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count87
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2017/11/22 v2.5 e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count88
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2018/01/01 v1.0k Graphics/color driver for pdftex
)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
)
\tchklst@entry@toks=\toks16
\c@tchklst@entryID=\count89

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bbding/bbding.sty
Package: bbding 1999/04/15 v1.01 Dingbats symbols
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/marginnote/marginnote.sty
Package: marginnote 2017/04/22 v1.2b non floating margin notes for LaTeX
\c@mn@abspage=\count90
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty
Package: longtable 2014/10/28 v4.11 Multi-page Table package (DPC)
\LTleft=\skip43
\LTright=\skip44
\LTpre=\skip45
\LTpost=\skip46
\LTchunksize=\count91
\LTcapwidth=\dimen103
\LT@head=\box26
\LT@firsthead=\box27
\LT@foot=\box28
\LT@lastfoot=\box29
\LT@cols=\count92
\LT@rows=\count93
\c@LT@tables=\count94
\c@LT@chunks=\count95
\LT@p@ftn=\toks17
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tabu/tabu.sty
Package: tabu 2011/02/26 v2.8 - flexible LaTeX tabulars (FC)

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty
Package: array 2016/10/06 v2.4d Tabular extension package (FMi)
\col@sep=\dimen104
\extrarowheight=\dimen105
\NC@list=\toks18
\extratabsurround=\skip47
\backup@length=\skip48
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/varwidth/varwidth.sty
Package: varwidth 2009/03/30 ver 0.92;  Variable-width minipages
\@vwid@box=\box30
\sift@deathcycles=\count96
\@vwid@loff=\dimen106
\@vwid@roff=\dimen107
)
\c@taburow=\count97
\tabu@nbcols=\count98
\tabu@cnt=\count99
\tabu@Xcol=\count100
\tabu@alloc=\count101
\tabu@nested=\count102
\tabu@target=\dimen108
\tabu@spreadtarget=\dimen109
\tabu@naturalX=\dimen110
\tabucolX=\dimen111
\tabu@Xsum=\dimen112
\extrarowdepth=\dimen113
\abovetabulinesep=\dimen114
\belowtabulinesep=\dimen115
\tabustrutrule=\dimen116
\tabu@thebody=\toks19
\tabu@footnotes=\toks20
\tabu@box=\box31
\tabu@arstrutbox=\box32
\tabu@hleads=\box33
\tabu@vleads=\box34
\tabu@cellskip=\skip49
))
(./Test_Checklist.aux)
\openout1 = `Test_Checklist.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count103
\scratchdimen=\dimen117
\scratchbox=\box35
\nofMPsegments=\count104
\nofMParguments=\count105
\everyMPshowfont=\toks21
\MPscratchCnt=\count106
\MPscratchDim=\dimen118
\MPnumerator=\count107
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count108
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks22
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+ding on input line 3.
 (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bbding/Uding.fd
File: Uding.fd 1996/02/01 v1.0 BBding font definitions
)
Package marginnote Info: \pdfoutput not 0 or unimportant and
(marginnote)             \pdflastxpos or \lastxpos available.
(marginnote)             Extended position detection mode activated.


! LaTeX Error: Environment Checklist undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.4 \begin{Checklist}
                     {Goal}
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.5     \Goal
          {open}{I have a trendy haircut}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


! LaTeX Error: Environment Checklist undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.6         \begin{Checklist}
                       {Task}
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.7             \Task
            {done}{Find a hairdresser}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.8             \Task
            {started}Make an appointment}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
l.8             \Task{started}Make an appointment}

I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.9             \Task
            {open}{Go to the hairdresser}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{Checklist}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.10        \end{Checklist}

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.11    \Goal
           {achieved}{I have a typed checklist}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{Checklist}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.12 \end{Checklist}

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

[1

{/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./Test_Checklist.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 2821 strings out of 493726
 38736 string characters out of 6148218
 103112 words of memory out of 5000000
 6371 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 4085 words of font info for 16 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 622 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 31i,5n,37p,819b,115s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/
amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on Test_Checklist.pdf (1 page, 15384 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 12 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 7 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

I apologize if I have included too much of the log file. I am relatively new to using and troubleshooting TeX/LaTeX, and I am still learning what is important and what is not. I'm thinking, though, that the example given in the documentation should process correctly, so maybe it is something I am missing about my two TeXLive installations.

Cheers,
Sean

Comment: The name of the environment is `CheckList` not `Checklist`. There is also an opening brace missing  before "Make".

Comment: Changing "Checklist" to "CheckList" solve the problem with the undefined environment, and I got so hung up on Error 1.4 with the undefined environment that I missed 1.8 and its missing brace.